# UITextField, automatically move to next after 1 character using Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitextfield

I have 4 UITextFields. After I enter the one character, I want the next `UITextField` to become active automatically, without having to press `next`.

I'm using Swift 2

Any idea?

Comment: `resignFirstResponder` for currentTextField and use `becomeFirstResponder` for textfield which you want to active

Comment: Enhanced syntax

Answer (score 0):

To select the next textField you have to assign the first Responder. You can use the delegate methods of the textField to determine when the textfield should become active.

Answer (score 0):

First set different tag for each `UITextField`. Then add `UIControlEvents.editingChanged` method.

When you connect `@IBOutlet`s and `@IBAction`s with your xib file, you'll get something like something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
      @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
      @IBOutlet weak var textField3: UITextField!
      @IBOutlet weak var textField4: UITextField!

      @IBAction func textChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
          if sender.hasText {
             switch sender {
             case textField1:
                textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
             case textField2:
                textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
             case textField3:
                textField4.becomeFirstResponder()
             default:
                sender.resignFirstResponder()
             }
          }
      }

  }
```

Comment: no need to tag them if you have all of them connected to the same action. Just `switch sender` and check `case textField1:`

Comment: you can also check `if sender.hasText`

Comment: Yeah, it would be cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: No need for the first `resignFirstResponder`, that will only make the keyboard blink.